# insert data into Mysql and show modal in one click codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following table:

http://i42.tinypic.com/sovfab.png

I need to insert all fields into a new table in mysql when I clicked on "plus" button. In adition I need to show this modal:

http://i39.tinypic.com/mrd63k.png

In resume, I need to insert data and show modal on the same click.

I'm using MVC with codeigniter.

I can insert data and show the modal if I did that independently.

- To insert data:

  I'm using the controller and all parameters were insert using the URL.
  **Example:** *Localhost/Index.php/Controller?Parameter1&Parameter2&Parameter3*
- To show modal:

I'm calling in the view with javascript function with `onclick="test()"` and the function has

> `function test(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }`

. Or more simply I can use

> `<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>`

Comment: What the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. 
I think you should try a ajax call

```
$.post( "/Index.php/Controller?Parameter1&Parameter2&Parameter3/", function( data ) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery if you like, its much easier and simpler

```
$(".plus").on("click",function(e){
    var postData ={};
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var td = tr.find('td');
    td.each(function(i,v){
        if(i< td.length-1){
            var key = $("#tab").find("th").eq(i).html();   
            postData[key]=$(this).html();
        }
    });
 //Now the parameters are ready send the ajax request
 $.post( "your_url", postData)
  .done(function( data ) {
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there you using form, to get fields, use:

```
    // This product objet to use in ajax
    var myData = $('#ID_FORM').serializeArray();        

    // This send to you page using POST
    $.ajax({
         url: 'test.php',
         data : myData,
         type: "post"
    });

    // Now, i recomend to use http://bootboxjs.com/
    // See docs, using this, look
    // Put data-attribute message in "A" to get it to use in modal box
    // use data-message
    // This plugin, need use bootstrap, is so easy

    $('a').on('click', function(){
        var msg = $(this).data('message');
        bootbox.alert(msg);
    });
```

I have helped